# Magento 2 Load Catalog Directly Using Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I want to create custom script to load the catalog data directly from Elastic search instead of loading through catalog model connection.

So if anyone has any idea then can you please guide me. I want to use this script with graphql.

Thanks

Comment: Are there some updates of this thread? Anyone has a solution?